# Google Smart Home integration with my IoT device (clarification needed)

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I am looking for some clarification to how Google Smart Home works. 
I am looking to integrate my current end device which control lights with Google Smart Home.

My end device is running a very small microcontroller utilizing an RTOS (Linux is not available)

**Here is how I see it (Please correct or comment)**

- To my understanding this requires me to host my own cloud service
  which will talk to my current end device?
- My cloud service will then talk to Google cloud service.
- My cloud service defines the protocol to talk to multiple end devices
- Google Smart Home define the protocol to talk to my cloud service

**Questions**

1. Is there any method of doing this without having my own cloud Service?

Comment: its a bit rubbish that google home devices cannot talk directly to local network endpoints. It would cut out a lot of middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a pretty basic summary of things - yes.

The crucial point there is that issuing a command to the Google Home does *not* have it send out a message on your local network. Google issues any commands from their network - not from your device.

This might seem like a minor detail, but it doesn't need to be a "cloud service" that you control that Google talks to. It *does* need to be a publicly accessible HTTPS endpoint. This could be a cloud service (and it would be in most cases), a public non-cloud server, or even just a public URL that has a tunnel to your private network (such as with ngrok).

The last is really how you'd get around having your own cloud service - you can setup the control on a local machine, and have a tunnel using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Comment: Thinking of this on a lager scale (1000s of devices in multiple homes) without a my own cloud service. I will need a public URL per device. How does Google Service know of these Public URL, once they become live?

Comment: You would need some sort of central server that you can use to facilitate requests to individual devices. Each execution request will contain a unique device id, which you can use to identify which end device you want.

However, there is the expectation of a central server to handle QUERY requests as well, returning to the Assistant the device state.

You should have some sort of service to store device states and handle Assistant requests. This can be done in a lightweight way with Firebase Functions and Realtime Database.

Answer (score 1):

I think a specific example may be beneficial: here's how to connect Google Home to your devices using an intermediary service like IFTTT:

1. Create a recipe (applet) on IFTTT to connect Google Assistant to an ngrok tunnel using the Webhook service.  This permits you to define a simple keyword phrase that the Google Home will recognize (like "Hey Google turn on my device").  The applet will then call a webhook - e.g. ngrok - with a custom command that you get to define (like "https://myngroktunnel.ngrok.io/Control.cgi?mydevice=on" ), where myngroktunnel is your ngrok tunnel address (see below #2) and Control.cgi is the CGI script that you have placed on your microcontroller (see below #3).
2. You would need to install and run ngrok on your microcontroller: this will connect the IFTTT applet to your microcontroller via the ngrok tunnel and give you a publicly-accessible URL that forwards requests to your microcontroller.  You would typically forward your ngrok tunnel to a specific port on your microcontroller where you are running a web server (e.g. Apache) with CGI scripts to control your device.  There are other secure tunnel services available on the web: ngrok is just one of them.  So, you do not have to host your own webservice, but you do have to use a tunnel to a publicly-accessible service.
3. The web server that you have placed on your microcontroller has CGI scripts that control your device (for example, let's say you have a Control.cgi script that turns your device on or off, given a command string like mydevice=on, e.g. the hook in the IFTTT applet is "/Control.cgi?mycommand=on"

Of course, the RTOS on your microcontroller muse be capable of running ngrok and a web server - this is why many people have chosen to use a single-board computer like the Raspberry Pi or Orange Pi running a form of linux to host and control their devices.   Since your device's RTOS is not linux, I would suggest getting a linux device which would then forward the request to your RTOS device over your LAN.