# create IoT device controlled by google home

Tags: iot, google-home

i want to make a IoT device (with raspberry) that can be controlled by google home (and voice commands). I see online that all configuration are:

Google Home <--------------->   IFTTT  ---------->   IoT Action

Is there a way to avoid IFTTT? I want to use a configuration like:

Google Home <----------------> IoT

What library or sdk do i need?

Thanks

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696978/google-smart-home-integration-with-my-iot-device-clarification-needed

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid IFTTT is to simply create your own Smart Home service.

Take a look [here](http://nilhcem.com/android-things/google-assistant-smart-home). I answered a similar question on StackOverflow a month back ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951977/connecting-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-google-home/) to it).