# connecting a raspberry pi to a google home

Tags: raspberry-pi, actions-on-google, google-home

I want to control my raspberry pi with my Google Home at college, but everything I find involves a server and opening a port which I can not do on my schools network.

Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: Could you not create an application similar to the google home app to connect to it? Might be a lot of work, but it’s a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Home has no way to directly control other devices on the same network or through other wireless protocols. Everything goes through an Internet-based service and expects to communicate with devices via a server-based proxy. How that server communicates with the device is up to the developer.

Depending on your needs and capabilities, you do have a few options.

One option, for example, is to use a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.io/) to create a tunnel between the device itself and a service run by ngrok on the public Internet. Calls to the public https address are sent to a service running locally on your device, and you can handle it accordingly.

Another is to have your device connect to a server and listen for command changes, and then execute those changes. If you don't want to run a server, you can even use something like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) - have your device listen for changes on the [real-time database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/) (which can use the HTTPS port to communicate as a client, so you don't open anything) and have something like a [Firebase Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions/) act as the webhook for your [Action](https://developers.google.com/actions/).

Answer (score 0):

Go through this blog post: http://nilhcem.com/android-things/google-assistant-smart-home

You will have to set up a OAuth server but as @Prisoner said you can use ngrok to tunnel the device to internet, BUT I would recommend using **"localtunnel"** as it provides a free static url and the set-up is also easy. NO Port Forwarding is required with this method.

More info on localtunnel setup:- 
[How to generate fixed url with ngrok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050182/how-to-generate-fixed-url-with-ngrok/39703680)

Moreover you need to activate the OAuth server only once for account linking & than you can close it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is to expose your Pi to the internet (using port forwarding, ngrok, or whatever) then set up an IFTTT [Google Assistant](https://ifttt.com/google_assistant) trigger to invoke a [webhook](https://ifttt.com/maker_webhooks) which points to your exposed Pi.